# Using Urllib instead of action in post form

Tags: python, amazon-s3, urllib2

I need to allow users to upload content directly to Amazon S3. This form works:

```
<form action="https://me.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' class="upload-form">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="videos/test.jpg">
    <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="<access_key>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read">
    <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="{{policy}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="{{signature}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload">
</form>
```

And in the function, I define policy and signature. However, I need to pass two variables to the form -- `Content-Type` and `Key`, which will only be known when the user presses the upload button. Thus, I need to pass these two variables to the template after the POST request but before the re-direction to Amazon.

It was suggested that I use urllib to do this. I have tried doing so the following way, but I keep getting an inscrutable HTTPError. This is what I currently have:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    # define the variables
    urllib2.urlopen("https://me.amazonaws.com/", 
                           urllib.urlencode([('key','videos/test3.jpg'),  
                           ('AWSAccessKeyId','<access_key'), 
                           ('acl','public-read'), 
                           ('policy',policy),
                           ('signature',signature),
                           ('Content-Type',content_type),
                           ('file',file)]))
```

I have also tried hardcoding all the values instead of using variables but still get the same error. What am I doing incorrectly and what do I need to change to be able to redirect the form to Amazon, so the content can be uploaded directly to Amazon?

Comment: Which http error is it given ? Did you supply all the fields (http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/proposals/post.html) for example i think you should set also the `Content-Type` header to `multipart/form-data` !?

Comment: @muad: How would I store the Content-Type as `multipart/form-data`, I already have Content-Type specified (even if it's wrong here). How would I enter it?

Comment: HTTPError at /videos/upload/
No exception supplied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend watching the form do its work with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), enabled and set to the Net tab.

After completing the POST, click its [+] icon to expand, study the Headers, POST, Response tabs to see what you are missing and/or doing wrong.

Next separate this script from Django and put into a standalone file.  Add one thing at a time to it and retest until it works.  The lines below should increase visibility into your script.

```
import httplib
httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
```

I tried poking around with urllib myself, but as I don't have an account on AWS I didn't get farther than getting a 400 Bad Request response.  Seems like a good sign, probably I just need valid host and key params etc.